# Can ps display only non kernel processes on Linux?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, ps, filter

How can I ask `ps` to display only user processes and not kernel threads?

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22121/what-do-the-brackets-around-processes-mean) to see what I mean...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This should do (under Linux):

```
ps --ppid 2 -p 2 --deselect
```

`kthreadd` (PID 2) has PPID 0 (*on Linux 2.6+*) but `ps` does not allow to filter for PPID 0; thus this work-around.

See also this [equivalent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78583/can-ps-display-only-non-kernel-processes-on-linux/755765#755765).

Comment: Nice, but how guaranteed is it that `kthreadd` is always PID 2?

Comment: @l0b0 I have no idea :-) You could do this in two steps: Determine the PID of `kthreadd`, then build the according `ps` call. How guaranteed is it that this thing will "always" be called "kthreadd"? A safe solution would be more complicated, run `ps` normally and parse the output, do some tests maybe.

Comment: [Others](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_kill_a_process_by_name.3F__I_need_to_get_the_PID_out_of_ps_aux_.7C_grep_....) have taught me it's a bad idea to look for the PID by looking for process names in `ps` output. There could easily be any number of processes with the same name.

Comment: In Linux 2.4 on x86 arch at least, those processes had ppid 1 so couldn't be distinguished that way.

Comment: Sorry for being a "ps noob", but how would I get an output similar to `ps aux` with that command?

Comment: to be like "ps -ef" do "ps --ppid 2 -p 2 --deselect -f" and to do it like "ps aux" do "ps --ppid 2 -p 2 --deselect u"

Comment: @Totor I checked and looks like it's the `x` flag that doesn't work with this. `ps au --ppid 2 -p 2 --deselect` works OK.

Comment: @Sankalp The `--deselect` option (can be shortened as `-N`) negates the specified conditions. `ps ax` shows the processes owned by anyone, with or without a tty (basicly all proceses), so `ps ax --deselect` shows none. If you look carefully, `ps a --deselect` won't show any process with a tty.

Answer (score 16):

In practice I found the following idiom enough:

```
ps auxf | grep -v ]$
```

It filters lines ending with brackets, which *might* result omitting unwanted entries but it's very unlikely. In exchange it's quite easy to remember and relatively quick to type.

Some processes like avahi-daemon add to their process name information in brackets (the hostname in the case of avahi-daemon) and will be filtered out by this command.

Answer (score 12):

One way to recognize kernel processes is that they don't use any user memory, so the vsz field is 0. This also catches zombies (thanks to [Stephane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78583/can-ps-display-only-non-kernel-processes-on-linux/78643?noredirect=1#comment116026_78643) for this observation), which can be eliminated based on their status.

```
ps axl | awk '$7 != 0 && $10 !~ "Z"'
```

To list just the PIDs:

```
ps -e -o pid= -o state= -o vsize= | awk '$2 != "Z" && $3 != 0 {print $1}'
```

Comment: Like my solution, it will also include zombie processes.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Good point, I've added a condition to the filter.

Answer (score 8):

One of the particularity of those processes is that they are not backed by an executable file, so you could do (*in zsh*):

```
ps /proc/[0-9]*/exe(^-@:h:t)
```

**Or with any POSIX shell:**

```
ps -p "$(find -L /proc/[0-9]*/exe ! -type l | cut -d / -f3 | paste -sd , -)"
```

That is check for processes whose `/proc/<pid>/exe` is a link to a file.

But that means you need to be superuser to be able to check the state of the `/proc/<pid>/exe` symlink.

**Edit**: As it happens the zombie processes (at least) satisfy the same condition, so if you don't want them excluded, you'd have to add them back. Like:

```
ps -p "$(
  { find -L /proc/[0-9]*/exe ! -type l | cut -d / -f3
    ps -Ao pid=,state= | sed -n 's/ Z//p'
  } | paste -sd , -)"
```

Note that `ps -f` shows those process names in square brackets not because they're kernel processes, but because they have an empty `argv[]` (so ps shows the process name instead of `argv[0]` there). You can have a user space process with an empty `argv[]` as well and you can have a process name with an `argv[0]` that's of the form `[some-string]` so filtering the `ps` output based on those square brackets is not a foolproof option.

Comment: This is non standard shell syntax, I reckon.

Comment: @Totor, as I said, the first one is `zsh` syntax. The second is standard POSIX `sh` (and `ps` and `find` and `cut` and `paste`) syntax. Of course `/proc` is not specified by POSIX.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it's **universal** (thanks for the edit). However, *Hauke Laging*'s answer is also pretty nice and straightforward as long as you don't deal with a 2.4 kernel.

Comment: @Totor, Hauke's answer also has the advantage of not requiring superuser priviledge. My answer works with 2.4 and 2.6/3 kernels, but I suppose there's not guarantee it will work in 4.x anyway.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I didn't think about root privileges. It can lead to mistakes since you still get an answer when you're not root, but it's *different* (so you must be cautious when counting them with, say `wc -l`). Well, I will accept *Hauke Laging*'s answer then, and give you an upvote. ;)

Comment: Stephane, can you edit your answer to specify that it works "as expected" (displays all user processes) only if you're root, please?

Comment: @Totor, I did from the start. `root` is the usual username with _superuser_ priviledge (uid 0)

Comment: Mea culpa, I didn't read carefully enough. Thank you Stephane.

Answer (score 3):

Although the question has aged a bit, there is an interesting new approach: Since version 4 of the **procps** package, you can set the environment variable `LIBPROC_HIDE_KERNEL`. If set, **ps(1)** and **top(1)** will display user space processes, only.

Extract from the manual:

> LIBPROC_HIDE_KERNEL
>
> Set this to any value to hide kernel threads
> normally displayed with the -e option. This is equivalent to selecting
> --ppid 2 -p 2 --deselect instead. Also works in BSD mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just parse the `ps` output and look for process names that are not in brackets:

```
ps aux | awk '$NF!~/^\[.+\]$/'
```

Comment: A slightly less unreliable way to get the list of users you're interested in: `awk -F: '$7 ~ home { print $1 }' /etc/passwd` -- but you'll still get processes that *mention* any such user name, and you'll leave the temp file lying around. I'll withdraw my downvote, but only because your third solution is reasonable.

Comment: Bah, you're right all the way, @KeithThompson, removed the others, they're not worth it. Could you help me clean up the (now) obsolete comments?

Comment: Note that `$NF` is the last word of the command line in `ps aux` output. Non-kernel processes can have `[...]` there. As I said in my answer the `[xxx]` notation is not because they are kernel processes, but because they have no command line (no argument) which is also allowed of non-kernel processes.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying this in busybox where `ps` is heavily simplified and the output is different, this variant of Gilles' great answer works well:

```
ps -o pid,user,comm,vsz,stat | awk '$4 != 0 && $5 !~ "Z"'
```

As per Gilles' answer, the methodology here is to find processes that don't use any user memory (`vsz col == 0), and filter out zombie processes (status col is not 'Z').

Output columns can be adjusted easily, as long as the 1-based awk field numbers are adjusted accordingly.  See the options your ps has available by putting in a bogus value and it will tell you.  For example:

```
$ ps -o foo
ps: bad -o argument 'foo', supported arguments: user,group,comm,args,pid,ppid,pgid,tty,vsz,stat,rss
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you only need the counts ...**
I had a similar need to filter kernel vs. user processes, but I only needed the respective counts of each. This was my solution:

```
ps -eo vsz,state | grep -v Z | awk '{p[$1==0]++} END {printf "%-16s %6d\n%-16s %6d\n%-16s %6d\n", "Kernel processes", p[1], "User processes", p[0], "Total processes", p[0]+p[1]}'
```

*Sample output*:

```
Kernel processes    353
User processes       52
Total processes     405
```

*Explanation*: I'm using the hack that VSZ=0 processes can be assumed to be kernel processes.  So with `awk`, I evaluate a comparison on VSZ (from `ps -eo vsize`), whether it equals zero.  The result of the comparison will be either a boolean 0 or 1.  I make an array `p[]`, and as I run down the list of processes, if it's a kernel process, I increment `p[1]++`.  Otherwise, as user process, I increment `p[0]++`.  After all the incrementing, I label and print the values (i.e. counts) for p[0] and p[1] in the `END { }` block.

*Edit*: Updated to filter out processes in zombie (Z) state.

Comment: _I'm using the hack that VSZ=0 processes can be assumed to be kernel processes._ – have you not read existing answers before posting which point out that this condition alone is not enough?

Comment: Thankls @PiotrDobrogost, I've updated the command to filter out zombie processes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, my friend, is not `ps`, but `pstree`.

First, identify the first kernel process. Its PID is commonly 1 on system without systemd and 2 with systemd.

Then use this command:

```
$ pstree -p <1 or 2> | grep -o '([0-9]\+)' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

The selected answer (one with ✅) is using another command:

```
$ ps --ppid 2 -p 2 --deselect
```

The problem with this `ps` command is that it only includes direct children but not all descendants. The `pstree` command includes all descendants. You can compare and count the output of these two commands (an easy way is using `| wc` ) to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I've created [psa](https://github.com/tpo/little_shell_scripts/blob/master/psa) script for that purpose. Note that it depends on the [linechop](https://github.com/tpo/little_shell_scripts/blob/master/linechop) tool.