# Linux: is it possible to see only kernel space threads/process?

Tags: linux-kernel, process

I know there are two "levels" of programs: User space and kernel space.

My question is: I want to see only kernel programs,or better: programs on kernel space.

Is this approach correct?

```
ps -ef|grep "\["

root         1     0  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 init [4]
root         2     0  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5     2  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7     2  0 20:23 ?        00:00:06 [rcu_sched]
root         8     2  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9     2  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root        10     2  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
root        11     2  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        13     2  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        14     2  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 [migration/2]
....
```

Comment: >is possible to see kernel space programs? ... Yes!  You simply need the correct astronomical filter on your CCD... ;-)

Comment: lsmod ?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsmod

Comment: @steve Kernel space programs are really strictly tangential to modules. Not all modules have processes, and not all processes are modules.

Comment: The question is wrong: you want to see kernel processes (or kernel threads, or kernel tasks) not kernel programs.... There is only one *program* involved: the *kernel* (and kernel modules are *added* into the kernel).

Comment: I will correct now

Comment: All process switch into kernel space when they make a syscall

Comment: Good answer on stackoverflow: [Identifying kernel threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56369641/427158)  - turned into bash code: [How to identify a thread is a kernel thread or not through `bash`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61940790/427158)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Kernel processes (or "kernel threads") are children of PID 2 (`kthreadd`), so this might be more accurate:

```
ps --ppid 2 -p 2 -o uname,pid,ppid,cmd,cls
```

Add `--deselect` to invert the selection and see only user-space processes.

(This question was pretty much an exact inverse of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78583/can-ps-display-only-non-kernel-processes-on-linux).)

In 2.4.* and older kernels, this PID 2 convention did not exist yet.

Comment: Is it always true ? See the fourth comment in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12213445/1971003

Comment: It is possible that in early 2.6.* kernels the conversion to the "child of PID 2" convention was not quite complete. As HighKing indicates there, the name of PID 2 had also not fully stabilized to `kthreadd` by 2.6.18. If you're interested in exact details, go to kernel.org and use the git browser interface to drill down into the early history of `kernel/kthread.c` file.

Answer (score 4):

Kernel threads do not use RAM at all (or at least are displayed not to use any):

```
ps -eo cmd,vsize,rss | grep -E ' 0 +0$'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have [`tuna`](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tuna) installed you can list all kernel threads like this:

```
$ tuna -U -P
                      thread       ctxt_switches
    pid SCHED_ rtpri affinity voluntary nonvoluntary             cmd 
  2      OTHER     0     0xff       290            1        kthreadd  
  3      OTHER     0     0xff         2            0          rcu_gp  
  4      OTHER     0     0xff         2            0      rcu_par_gp  
  6      OTHER     0        0        13            0 kworker/0:0H-kblockd  
  9      OTHER     0     0xff         2            0    mm_percpu_wq  
  10     OTHER     0        0       448            0     ksoftirqd/0
[..]
```