# ps: show only processes owned by root, without showing kernel threads

Tags: shell, process, ps

I know how to hide kernel threads from `ps`:

```
/bin/ps --pid 2 --ppid 2 --deselect -o user:10,pid,stat,pcpu,pmem,tty,start_time,cmd
```

and I know how to show only processes owned by root:

```
/bin/ps -U root -o user:10,pid,stat,pcpu,pmem,tty,start_time,cmd
```

but how do I show only processes owned by root, while excluding kernel threads?

Combining the two above commands does not work:

```
/bin/ps --pid 2 --ppid 2 --deselect -U root -o user:10,pid,stat,pcpu,pmem,tty,start_time,cmd
```

Comment: Logical since *deselect* will apply to both pid, ppid and U specifications. I suggest you find another way to ignore kernel threads than using pid and ppid selectors deselected  @StépaheChazelas answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78583/can-ps-display-only-non-kernel-processes-on-linux could possibly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do the selection by hand using `awk`:

```
ps -o user:10,pid,stat,pcpu,pmem,tty,start_time,cmd -p $(
  ps -Ao pid= -o sid= -o uid= | awk '$2 && ! $3 {print $1}'
)
```

Here checking for the session id which is 0 for kernel threads.

Comment: does this show real or effective uid root processes ?