# How can I learn the purpose of the various kernel processes?

Tags: linux-kernel, documentation

(Related: [What do the brackets around processes mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22121/135943))

I'd like to really understand what I'm looking at better.  I'd rather not need to dig through actual kernel source code just for a quick understanding.

For instance, I looked up `kacpid` with initially very little success.  Eventually I discovered that it is the kernel ACPI Daemon, and reading up on the [Wikipedia page for ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) clarified in general what that process is all about.

What I would love would be a series of *simple* definitions, such that looking up `kacpid` would give me something like:

> **kacpid:** Stands for kernel ACPI daemon.  ACPI is the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface, a set of standards relating to handling of various "states" including sleep, power off, hibernate; and also states relating to CPU power saving.

Now I'm trying to look up `kblockd` and all the Google results show is people having trouble running out of memory—not very good for understanding why this process exists!

I could just ask "What is `kblockd` all about," and I'm interested in that—but:

Given the vast amount of online and off-line documentation relating to Linux (man pages, info pages, POSIX specs, etc.), isn't there a standard solution for the **[general problem](https://xkcd.com/974/)** of learning what various kernel processes *mean*, and what they're doing?  What is that standard solution?

Answer (score 4):

There is no single repository of documentation about Linux kernel threads. Some basic documentation of the Linux kernel exists in the [`Documentation`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/) directory, but there is no specific part about kernel threads (some threads are mentioned in passing in the documentation of the feature they participate in). Beyond this, the (excuse for a) documentation consists, in order of decreasing accessibility, of the [LWN articles](http://lwn.net/Kernel/), the source code, and the [LKML archives](https://lkml.org/). The general philosophy of Linux kernel documentation is that if you can't read C code fluently and aren't prepared to spend some time digging through email discussions, you don't deserve to understand what the kernel does.

The easiest way to find information about a thread by name is to [search for the name in the kernel source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/search?v=4.5).
For example, [`kblockd`](https://www.google.com/search?q=kblockd&sitesearch=lxr.free-electrons.com%2Fsource&gws_rd=ssl) is created in [`blk-core.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/blk-core.c?v=4.5). [It's a work queue](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/blk-core.c?v=4.5#L3540). A bit of LKML searching leads you to its inception with [`kblockd.patch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/akpm/patches/2.5/2.5.70/2.5.70-mm8/broken-out/kblockd.patch). It handles asynchronous requests (that's what a work queue does), specifically requests to block devices (i.e. disks and such).

Comment: It's not necessary to start with LKML to find where it originated. It might be sufficient to try `git blame` and `git log` first.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
x="kblockd"
man -k "$x"
locate "$x"
for i in $(locate "$x") ; do
    dpkg -S "$i"
done
```

This will produce a list of packages related to your "`object`". Read `man dpkg` to see how to get a list of files in a package.

Comment: I use RHEL/CentOS, but this might be handy for Debian.

Comment: `kblockd` is not a program, it's a thread in the kernel. There is no file called `kblockd`. This is completely irrelevant.