# Process appears with square brackets ([]) around name after being SIGKILL'd

Tags: linux-kernel, process, ps, sigkill

I am executing and killing a process as follows:

```
python some_script.py &; pid=$!; sleep 5; kill -9 $!; ps -o pid,sid,uid,state,start,command
```

In other words: I execute a script in the background, record its process id, sleep 5 seconds, terminate it with a SIGKILL, and finally display the list of processes. The script itself is quite memory intensive. Its source code is included at the end of the question.

The output of `ps` is

```
   PID    SID      UID S  STARTED COMMAND
 72014  73317 22563342 R 20:56:36 [python]
<... other processes>
```

This is followed by confirmation that the process was successfully killed:

```
[1]  + killed     python some_script.py
```

My question: **why is the Python process displayed with brackets around its name in `ps`?**

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22121/what-do-the-brackets-around-processes-mean), square brackets indicate that the process's arguments are unavailable. Usually because the process in question is a kernel process, although clearly that isn't the case here. One possibility that I can think of is that the process's memory has been wiped, including its stack, which contains the list of arguments. But if the process's memory is being wiped by the kernel, shouldn't its state be DYING or ZOMBIE instead of RUNNING?

---

Source code for `some_script.py`:

```
import asyncio


async def create_tasks(n_tasks):
    tasks = [task() for _ in range(n_tasks)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def task():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(create_tasks(1000000))
```

Comment: Maybe it's just a race? There's no guarantee that the signal has been delivered when `kill` returns, AFAIK. So it might be killed while `ps` is in the middle of getting process information

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is in the `ps` man page:

> Sometimes the process args will be unavailable; when this happens, ps will instead print the executable name in brackets.

What this means is that the procps library tries to read `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` and if it is empty it will print the **command name** which is the second field in `/proc/<PID/stat` after removing any parenthesis "(...)" and put brackets "[...]" around it. For `ps` this is the `comm` field.

Changing your command line slightly:

```
$ python3 some_script.py &  pid=$!; sleep 5; kill -9 $!; echo CMDLINE BELOW ; cat -e /proc/${pid}/cmdline ; echo COMM BELOW ; cut -f 2 -d' ' /proc/${pid}/stat ; echo PS BELOW ; ps -o pid,sid,uid,state,start,comm,command ${pid}
[1] 62187
CMDLINE BELOW
COMM BELOW
(python3)
PS BELOW
    PID     SID   UID S  STARTED COMMAND         COMMAND
  62187   21814  1000 R 16:37:49 python3         [python3]
```

You'll notice
As to why the arguments are not available, basically, the process has been killed but not fully gone yet as @muru stated.

Also, the other answer saying the brackets mean a kernel thread isn't fully correct.  Kernel threads are just a special case of a process not having a command line.

Comment: > You'll notice As to why the arguments are not available, basically, the process has been killed but not fully gone yet as @muru stated.

This makes sense to me. But if the process has been killed but not yet terminated, why is it still in the RUNNING state? Shouldn't it have transitioned to ZOMBIE?